# How to change wallpaper and make transparent caps in compiz cube?

Tags: 12.10, compiz, cube

How do I change the wallpaper and make them transparent for the top en bottom cap. I can not find the option in compiz setting mananger. There is only the option to set the collors, and the transparent option does not even work..

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 x64

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently in the latest version of Compiz its not possible (I've been looking for it myself).

You can downgrade Compiz. However, this could have issues with Unity (Which i turned off anyway).

Maybe in a later version they will bring this back.